# Prove that $(1−x)^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}−x\frac{dy}{dx}+p^2y=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

Prove that $$(1−x)^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}−x\frac{dy}{dx}+p^2y=0 $$

where $$y = \sin(pt)$$ and $$ x =\sin(t) $$

please, tell me how this makes sense, shouldn't the second derivative be $0$?

I am wrestling with this every day for about a month and can't make sense of it.

Comment: It just means that $y =\sin(p \arcsin x)$. This function is closely related to Chebyshev polynomials, which satisfy differential equations like the one you have there.

Comment: Please check if the first factor is as written or rather is $(1-x^2)$.

Comment: But  y = sin(p*arcsinx)   is not  
  y = sin(p*t) . And we are differentiated in terms of x, and yet we have t, and t is not mentioned to be a function of x.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann No, it is unfortunately not

Comment: Then your task has an error, probably a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty is to make sense of $dy/dx$ when $x$ and $y$ are both parameterized by $t$. One approach would be to write $t = \arcsin x$, so $y = \sin(p\arcsin x)$. This makes for an unwieldy expression to differentiate twice.

Another approach is to write $$dy/dx = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} = \frac{p\cos pt}{\cos t}.$$ Then you would have
$$d^2y/dx^2 = \frac{d\left( \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} \right)/dt}{dx/dt}$$
$$=\frac{d\left( \frac{p\cos pt}{\cos t} \right)/dt}{\cos t}.$$
You should be able to continue from here using the quotient rule. Then you can use the computed expressions to verify the original equation.

Comment: I just asked S.Dolan the same question, but can you tell me why should we divide by dx/dt , can't we just take the derivative of the first derivative?

Comment: It's because your goal is to find the derivative(s) *with respect to $x$*, not $t$. The rule is $$dy/dx = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}.$$ Note very carefully that we are expressing the derivative **with respect to x** in terms of the derivatives **with respect to t**.

Comment: (continued) Think of this as the chain rule rearranged. If $y$ is a function of $x$, and $x$ is a function of $t$, then $$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}.$$ Now divide both sides by $\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Comment: But I have to understand why did we do divide by dx/dt the second time, didn't we found the derivative with respect to x in terms of the derivatives with respect to t, Why not just take the derivative of the first derivative to find the second?

Comment: As I said, it's because it needs to be **with respect to x** both times. Each time, you use the fact that (as explained in 2 previous comments) $$\frac{d}{d\boxed{x}}(\textrm{something}) = \frac{\frac{d(\textrm{something})}{d\boxed{t}}}{\frac{dx}{d\boxed{t}}}.$$ You are *never* just "taking the derivative". You are always "taking the derivative with respect to a specific variable". People usually leave that out, but it is absolutely *critical* to what is meant. There's no such thing as "the derivative". There's only "the derivative with respect to" some target variable.

Comment: (continued) If you don't divide by $dx/dt$, then you will have only partially computed what you want. You will only have computed the numerator of what's shown above. That's not the whole story.

Comment: In other notation: If you don't divide, you would be finding $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$, not $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}.$

Answer (score 1):

There is some abuse of notation involved, as $y$ is defined as a function of $t$, but its derivatives are written as if it were a function of $x$. To resolve this, write $y$ as composite function $y(x(t))$. There is no need to get more specific than this.

You can use that by the chain rule
$$
\frac{dy(x(t))}{dt}=\frac{dy(x(t))}{dx}\frac{dx(t)}{dt}
$$
and in the second derivative applying chain and product rule
$$
\frac{d^2y(x(t))}{dt^2}=\frac{d^2y(x(t))}{dx^2}\left(\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\right)^2+\frac{dy(x(t))}{dx}\frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2}.
$$
Now we can insert $y(x(t))=\sin(pt)$ etc. to get the derivatives in the equation,
\begin{align}
p\cos(pt)&=\frac{dy}{dx}\cos(t)\\
-p^2\sin(pt)&=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\cos^2(t)-\frac{dx}{dx}\sin(t)
\end{align}
However, inserting the trigonometric identity $\sin^2t+\cos^2t=1$ into the last equation and inserting back $\sin(t)=x$ etc. we already  get the differential equation for $y(x)$,
$$
(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+p^2y=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The relation you are trying to prove is incorrect.

Assuming the relation you meant to prove was 
$$
(1-x^2) \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+p^2y = 0
$$
here is what you do:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt} = \frac{p\cos(pt)}{\cos t} \\
x \frac{dy}{dx}  = p \cos(pt) \tan t
$$

$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{p\cos(pt)}{\cos t} \right) = \frac{1}{dx/dt} \frac{d}{dt} \frac{p\cos(pt)}{\cos t} = \frac{1}{\cos t} \left( \frac{
-p^2\sin(pt)\cos t+p\cos(pt)\sin t}{\cos^2 t}\right)
\\ (1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =(1-\sin^2 t) \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \cos^2t \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =
\frac{
-p^2\sin(pt)\cos t+p\cos(pt)\sin t}{\cos t}
\\ (1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = -p^2\sin(pt) + p\cos(pt) \tan t
$$
Add these together to get 
$$
(1-x^2) \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x\frac{dy}{dx}+p^2y = -p^2\sin(pt) + p\cos(pt) \tan t
+p \cos(pt) \tan t + p^2 y = 0
$$
since $y = \sin t$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}/\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{p\cos(pt)}{\cos(t)}$$

and this does not have zero derivative in the way that was worrying you.

Comment: But there we required to find not only the first but the second derivative

Comment: Yes - just do the same 'trick'. Differentiate wrt t and then divide by dx/dt.

Comment: I've just done this and would stress that the original d.e. does have $(1-x^2)$ as @ Dr. Lutz Lehmann has already suggested.

Comment: Forgive if come as ignorant, but why should we divide by dx/dt, can't we just take the derivative of the first derivative?

Comment: Because we want to differentiate wrt x but its easier to differentiate wrt t and then divde by dx/dt.